# Query API returning an empty response

Tags: php, xampp, postman

Hi guys I'm working for a couple of months with xampp and PHPMyAdmin to send and fetch data from MySQL database on localhost, and since the week I got an empty body response when I send my requests
I don't know why I didn't change anything in my PHP code and the thing that frustrates me that that the  Select request API is not working all the others work fine update, insert ...
and when I run the same query on MySQL database it works fine
I will be happy to get some help from u guys.
this my code in index.php

```
                $db = new DbOperation();
                                $Bars = $db->Bars_Listing_name_adress();
            
                if(count($Bars)<=0){
                    $response['error'] = true; 
                    $response['message'] = 'Nothing found in the database';
                }else{
                    $response['error'] = false; 
                    $response['Bars'] = $Bars;
                }
            break;
```

and this the code in dboperations.php

```
    //get the list of the bars name and adresse for the api 
    public function Bars_Listing_name_adress(){
        $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT Bar_Name,Adress,Zip_code,City,Country FROM Bars");
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($Bar_Name,$Adress,$Zip_code,$City,$Country );
        $Bars = array();
        
        while($stmt->fetch()){
            $temp = array(); 
            
            $temp['Bar_Name'] = $Bar_Name; 
                    $temp['Adress'] = $Adress; 
            $temp['Zip_code'] = $Zip_code; 
                    $temp['City'] = $City;
                    $temp['Country'] = $Country;
        
            array_push($Bars, $temp);
        }
        return $Bars;
```

and when I call it in Postman

```
http://localhost/WebApi/v1/?op=Bars_Listing_name_adress
```

I get an empty response which is weird

```
POST
http://localhost/WebApi/v1/?op=Bars_Listing_name_adress&=
16:17:11.176
Pretty
Raw
Request Headers:
Content-Type:"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
cache-control:"no-cache"
Postman-Token:"1093116d-58aa-4933-a571-99e42c0b203d"
User-Agent:"PostmanRuntime/7.6.0"
Accept:"*/*"
Host:"localhost"
accept-encoding:"gzip, deflate"
content-length:""
Response Headers:
Date:"Sat, 31 Oct 2020 15:17:11 GMT"
Server:"Apache/2.4.43 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.1.1g PHP/7.3.16 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3"
X-Powered-By:"PHP/7.3.16"
Content-Length:"0"
Keep-Alive:"timeout=5, max=100"
Connection:"Keep-Alive"
Content-Type:"text/html; charset=UTF-8"
Response Body:
```

but when I call any other request in the same PHP file it works so the problem is only happening with select without the where clausal
I will be happy to get some help from you guys thx !!

Comment: Are you echo'ing the result anywhere in your code?

Comment: literally part way through typing the same thing as @LawrenceCherone! Also you're saying it did work, so has something changed?  Is some data date bound, did you accidentally delete some stuff while testing a `DELETE` request?  Have you looked in the logs / turned on errors to make sure nothing's going wrong in the background?

Comment: debugging API's can be a bit of a pain if you don't have testing.  Writing some tests would be a really good place to start ideally (appreciate that new dev's don't know about / start learning about testing till much further down the line, which is a shame really in some respects).  If you don't have tests, then make sure you can actually hit the end point by running a `var_dump()` and then `die()`.  Also try hitting the endpoint in a browser rather than postman to make sure it's not a postman issue

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers. I just solved the problem. It was a decoding problem, I solved it with `utf8_encode`:

```
function utf8ize($d) {
    if (is_array($d)) {
        foreach ($d as $k => $v) {
            $d[$k] = utf8ize($v);
        }
    } else if (is_string ($d)) {
        return utf8_encode($d);
    }
    return $d;
}
echo json_encode(utf8ize($response));
    //echo json_encode($response);
```